# Spring Data Rest Overriding Default GET verb

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am trying override the default GET Verb for the API to add some more specific details.

I have created a restController and a Get requestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resources<User>> getUsers(Pageable pageable) {

    Page<User> users = userReposiotry.findAll(pageable);
    Resources<User> userResources = new Resources<>(users);

    return new ResponseEntity<Resources<User>>(userResources, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It works great but it does not return the links and other additional information that would be available if not overwritten.

The custom returns:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "admin",
        "registrationDate": "2015-11-18T21:04:54.000+0000",
        "name": "Admin",
        "email": "admin@admin.com",
        "enabled": true,
        "dateOfBirth": "2015-11-18",
        "imageIdentifier": null,
        "confirmationKey": ""
      }]
  }
}
```

While the original:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "admin",
        "registrationDate": "2015-11-18T21:04:54.000+0000",
        "name": "Admin",
        "email": "admin@admin.com",
        "enabled": true,
        "dateOfBirth": "2015-11-18",
        "imageIdentifier": null,
        "confirmationKey": "",
        "_links": {
          "self": [
            {
              "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
            },
            {
              "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users"
            }
          ],
          "user": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1{?projection}",
            "templated": true
          },
          "inviteToApps": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/inviteToApps"
          },
          "userRoles": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/userRoles"
          },
          "currencyTokens": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/currencyTokens"
          },
          "workoutAttendees": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/workoutAttendees"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/users"
    },
    "search": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/search"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 7,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

How can add the relation to the custom one like in the original?

Comment: spring data rest implement HATEOAS by default. (This is the REST mechanism that adds all the links in there). If you override it, you have to implement HATEOAS yourself in the controller layer.

Comment: Which annotation did you put on the controller class? @RestController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return a custom Bean, Map etc. instead of ResponseEntity:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object getUsers(Pageable pageable) {

    Page<User> users = userReposiotry.findAll(pageable);
    Resources<User> userResources  = new Resources<>(users);

    List<MyCustomUser> customUsers = [...]

    return customUSers;
}

// "some more specific details" in MyCustomUser
public class MyCustomUser extends User{

    private List<Links> links;

    // TODO: constructor, getter, setter.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you return entities, not resources. Try this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<User>>> getUsers(Pageable pageable) {

  Page<User> users = userReposiotry.findAll(pageable);
  Resources<Resource<User>> userResources = Resources.wrap(users);
```